# RegExp не учитывает переносы строк

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Я написал регулярку `new RegExp('(<%--)(.*)(--%>)','gim')`, которая должна находить все что заключено в последовательность символов `<%--` `--%>`. В пределах одной строки это работает нормально, но если между последовательностями символов `<%--` `--%>` будет перенос строки - то все сломается. Ловить перенос строки я решил такой регуляркой: `(<%--)([\s\S]*)(--%>)`, но она не работает правильно.

Подскажите, как правильно написать регулярку которая будет учитывать переносы строк?

Comment: _но она не работает правильно_ — а именно?

Comment: перенос строки, это \n (либо \r, либо \n\r)

Comment: @AlexeyTen протестируйте здесь: regex101.com - поймете в чем именно косяк

Comment: Алло, это вам нужна помощь или мне?

Comment: @Stanislav я это понимаю, какраз таки [\s\S]* будет их искать, но... не работает

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/cZ6oI8/1 works for me

Comment: @AlexeyTen, оно не работает и для вас) Добавьте больше текста, или вот: https://regex101.com/r/cZ6oI8/2 Такой регексп выделяет много лишнего, в т.ч. что выходит за пределы последовательностей нужных символов

Comment: @sanu0074 так это вы должно добавить больше информации в вопрос. А не я вытягивать из вас подробносить клещами…

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://regex101.com/r/cZ6oI8/3

```
var re = /(<%--)([\s\S]*?)(--%>)/g;
```

По умолчанию квантификатор `*` «жадный» и старается захватить как можно больше символов. Что бы ограничить его жадность надо добавить к нему флаг `?` (не путать с квантификатором `?`).

Comment: Вот видите, все же ясно вам было в вопросе, и к чему были ваши комменты про клещи....

Comment: @sanu0074 нигде в вопросе нет примера текста и знания о том, что таких блоков может быть больше одного. Научитесь правильно задавать вопросы и когда у вас просят подробности, давайте их, а не вставайте в позу.

Comment: я дал ссылку с примером, указал что должно искать, как работает как нет. Ошибку вам подсвечиват regex101.com. Просто вы были не внимательны. Вам не стоит нервничать и проявлять невежество, т.к. это не имеет смысла и никому от этого лучше не будет

Comment: Ссылку вы дали в седьмом комментарии, а должны были в самом начале и вообще в посте.

Answer (score 1):

Рекомендую пробовать так (для тех кто столкнётся):

```
new RegExp('(<%--)((?:.|\n)*?)(--%>)','g')
```

лично у меня не работал поиск с помощью `[\s\S]*?` (дебажил в chrome console), несмотря на то что во всех справках он указывается как самый верный, а также на ресурсах где обычно тестят регулярные выражения - такие как regex101.com, jsfiddle.net - всё работает.

в идеале должны работать оба способа (по логике вещей):

`([\s\S]*?)` - поскольку \s - любой пробельный символ (включая табы и переводы), а \S - любой символ кроме пробельного.

`((?:.|\n)*?)` - поскольку `.` - любой символ кроме переноса строки, `\n` - сам перенос. читается сложнее (используются "незахватывающие скобки"), но надёжнее

[подробнее о RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)

Comment: Никогда не используйте `(?:.|\n)*?`, это очень неэффективный шаблон, сильно тормозящий поиск с регулярными выражениями. Вместо него используйте  `[^]` / `[\s\S]` / `[\d\D]` / `[\w\W]`. В Chrome можно использовать модификатор `s` c `.`: `/<.*?>/gs`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew есть подтверждения в виде каких-либо замеров? либо ссылка на информацию где почитать, почему и на сколько такой шаблон тормозит. было бы интересно

Comment: Тут даже замеры не очень нужны, если понимаете, как работают регулярные выражения. Там, где чередование, всегда бэктрекинг, который "медленно превращается" из помощника во вредителя. Вот [проблема](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38883448) и-за этого шаблона в Java. [PCRE](https://regex101.com/r/V8Juhq/1) не может обработать очень длинные совпадения (c `[\s\S]*?` тоже будут проблемы, но [меньше](https://regex101.com/r/V8Juhq/2)). В JavaScript этот шаблон поустойчивее, но всё равно проигрывает в эффективности всем остальным.

Comment: А `[\s\S]*?` у вас не работал, потому что вместо литерала вы использовали конструктор RegExp. В общем, правильный ответ уже дан Alexey Ten'ом.